# Xcode API and Documentation in a seperate window?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

When i open up the reference with cmd + shift + 0, the window opens up in in the same window as my code, but i like to tab back and forth between things. Is there a way to have it in a seperate window or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the menu item instead of the shortcut key-combo. I always get a separate window when I use the menu item.

Comment: Yeah i get it in a window but my dream is to be able to cmd-tab to it as if its not inside of xcode :D